# I cant send the FormData to the php

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a form that collects all the information about the students and able to upload a file. Now, my problem is I am using ajax to send this values to PHP. But I cant send the **formData** to my php script. I use inspect Element and but no errors to be found.

Here is my Form:

I use onclick event to send the input value to my JS file.

```
<form class="needs-validation" id="studentAdmissionForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return false;" novalidate>

        <legend>Student's Information</legend>
        <hr>

        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
            <label for="lrn">Learner's Reference Number: *</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="lrn" id="lrn" placeholder="LRN" maxlength="12" oninput="javascript: if(this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" required>
            <div class="invalid-tooltip">
              Please provide your LRN!
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
            <label for="studentFname">First name: *</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="studentFname" id="studentFname" placeholder="First name" maxlength="64" required>
            <div class="valid-tooltip">
              Looks good!
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
            <label for="studentLname">Last name: *</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="studentLname" id="studentLname" placeholder="Last name" maxlength="64" required>
            <div class="valid-tooltip">
              Looks good!
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
            <label for="studentMname">Middle name: *</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="studentMname" id="studentMname" placeholder="Middle name" maxlength="64" required>
            <div class="valid-tooltip">
              Looks good!
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
            <label for="studentSname">Suffix name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="studentSname" id="studentSname" placeholder="eg. Jr" maxlength="64">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label for="gender">Gender: *</label>
            <select class="custom-select" name="gender" id="gender" required>
              <option value="">Select Gender</option>
              <option value="m">Male</option>
              <option value="f">Female</option>
            </select>
            <div class="invalid-tooltip">Please select your gender!</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label for="dob">Date of Birth: *</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="dob" id="dob" required>
            <div class="invalid-tooltip">
              Specify your date of birth!
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label for="citizenship">Citizenship:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="citizenship" id="citizenship" placeholder="Citizenship" maxlength="64">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label for="religion">Religion: *</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="religion" id="religion" placeholder="Religion" maxlength="64" required>
            <div class="valid-tooltip">
              Looks good!
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label for="ethnicity">Ethnic Group:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ethnicity" id="ethnicity" placeholder="Ethnic Group" maxlength="64">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label for="motherTongue">Mother Tongue:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="motherTongue" id="motherTongue" placeholder="Mother Tongue" maxlength="64">
          </div>
        </div>

        <legend class="mt-5">Contact Details</legend>
        <hr>

        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label for="houseNum">House No. / Unit No: *</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="houseNum" id="houseNum" placeholder="#" maxlength="64" required>
            <div class="valid-tooltip">
              Looks good!
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-8 mb-3">
            <label for="street">Street: *</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="street" id="street" placeholder="Street" maxlength="64" required>
            <div class="valid-tooltip">
              Looks good!
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label for="village">Subdivision / Village / Building:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="village" id="village" placeholder="Subd, Village or Building" maxlength="64">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label for="brgy">Barangay: *</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="brgy" id="brgy" placeholder="Barangay" maxlength="64" required>
            <div class="valid-tooltip">
              Looks good!
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label for="city">City / Municipality: *</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" id="city" placeholder="City" maxlength="64" required>
            <div class="valid-tooltip">
              Looks good!
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label for="province">Province: *</label>
            <select class="custom-select" name="province" id="province" required>
              <option value="Tawi Tawi">Tawi-Tawi</option>
              <option value="Zambales">Zambales</option>
              <option value="Zamboanga Del Norte">Zamboanga Del Norte</option>
              <option value="Zamboanga Del Sur">Zamboanga Del Sur</option>
              <option value="Zamboanga Sibugay">Zamboanga Sibugay</option>
            </select>
            <div class="invalid-tooltip">Specify your province!</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label for="zip">Zip Code: *</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="zip" id="zip" placeholder="xxxx" maxlength="4" oninput="javascript: if(this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" required>
            <div class="valid-tooltip">
              Looks good!
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label for="tel">Telephone No:</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="tel" id="tel" placeholder="Telephone No." maxlength="7" oninput="javascript: if(this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label for="mobile">Mobile No: *</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="mobile" id="mobile" placeholder="09xxxxxxxxx" maxlength="12" oninput="javascript: if(this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" required>
            <div class="valid-tooltip">
              Looks good!
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label for="email">Email address: *</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="example@domain.com" maxlength="64" required>
            <div class="valid-tooltip">
              Looks good!
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <legend class="mt-5">Guardian's Information</legend>
        <hr>

        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label for="fatherName">Father's Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fatherName" id="fatherName" placeholder="Lastname, Firstname & Middle Initial" maxlength="64">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label for="fatherNum">Contact No:</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="fatherNum" id="fatherNum" placeholder="Contact No." maxlength="12" oninput="javascript: if(this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label for="motherName">Mother's Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="motherName" id="motherName" placeholder="Lastname, Firstname & Middle Initial" maxlength="64">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label for="motherNum">Contact No:</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="motherNum" id="motherNum" placeholder="Contact No." maxlength="12" oninput="javascript: if(this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label for="guardianName">Guardian's Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="guardianName" id="guardianName" placeholder="Lastname, Firstname & Middle Initial" maxlength="64">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label for="guardianNum">Contact No:</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="guardianNum" id="guardianNum" placeholder="Contact No." maxlength="12" oninput="javascript: if(this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);">
          </div>
        </div>

        <legend class="mt-5">Upload File (Optional)</legend>
        <hr>

        <p class="mb-3">To ease up the registration and enrollment procedure, you may attach a copy of the admission requirements (e.g. Form137, Transcript of Records, PSA (formerly NSO) Issued Birth Certificate, etc.).</p>
        <p class="lead">Attach Files (Maximum of 10MB and allowed formats are: .JPG, .PNG, .DOC, .DOCX, .ZIP, .RAR and .PDF)</p>

        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <div class="custom-file">
              <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="file" id="file">
              <label class="custom-file-label" for="file">Choose file</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="admissionBtn" id="admissionBtn" onclick="submitStudentData()">Submit</button>
        <span id="status"></span>

      </form>
```

In my JS file:

Here's how I send the value and the file to my PHP script

```
function submitStudentData() {
    var lrn = _("lrn").value;
    var studentFname = _("studentFname").value;
    var studentLname = _("studentLname").value;
    var studentMname = _("studentMname").value;
    var studentSname = _("studentSname").value;
    var gender = _("gender").value;
    var dob = _("dob").value;
    var citizenship = _("citizenship").value;
    var religion = _("religion").value;
    var ethnicity = _("ethnicity").value;
    var motherTongue = _("motherTongue").value;
    var houseNum = _("houseNum").value;
    var street = _("street").value;
    var village = _("village").value;
    var brgy = _("brgy").value;
    var city = _("city").value;
    var province = _("province").value;
    var zip = _("zip").value;
    var tel = _("tel").value;
    var mobile = _("mobile").value;
    var email = _("email").value;
    var fatherName = _("fatherName").value;
    var fatherNum = _("fatherNum").value;
    var motherName = _("motherName").value;
    var motherNum = _("motherNum").value;
    var guardianName = _("guardianName").value;
    var guardianNum = _("guardianNum").value;
    var file = _("file").files[0];
    var successStatus = _("successStatus");
    var status = _("status");

    var formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("lrn", lrn);
    formData.append("studentFname", studentFname);
    formData.append("studentLname", studentLname);
    formData.append("studentMname", studentMname);
    formData.append("studentSname", studentSname);
    formData.append("gender", gender);
    formData.append("dob", dob);
    formData.append("citizenship", citizenship);
    formData.append("religion", religion);
    formData.append("ethnicity", ethnicity);
    formData.append("motherTongue", motherTongue);
    formData.append("houseNum", houseNum);
    formData.append("street", street);
    formData.append("village", village);
    formData.append("brgy", brgy);
    formData.append("city", city);
    formData.append("province", province);
    formData.append("zip", zip);
    formData.append("tel", tel);
    formData.append("mobile", mobile);
    formData.append("email", email);
    formData.append("fatherName", fatherName);
    formData.append("fatherNum", fatherNum);
    formData.append("motherName", motherName);
    formData.append("motherNum", motherNum);
    formData.append("guardianName", guardianName);
    formData.append("guardianNum", guardianNum);
    formData.append("file", file);

    if(lrn == "" || studentFname == "" || studentLname == "" || studentMname == "" || gender == "" || dob == "" || religion == "" ||
        houseNum == "" || street == "" || brgy == "" || city == "" || province == "" || zip == "" || mobile == "" || email == "") {
        status.innerHTML = "<p class='red statusMsg'><i class='fa fa-exclamation-triangle' aria-hidden='true'></i> Please fill out all required fields!</p>";
    } else {
        _('admissionBtn').disabled = true;
        status.innerHTML = "<p class='statusMsg'><i class='fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin' aria-hidden='true'></i> Please wait...</p>";

        var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "inc/admission.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
                if(ajax.responseText != 'success') {
                    status.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                    _('admissionBtn').disabled = false;
                } else {
                    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
                    $('#studentAdmissionForm')[0].reset();
                    successStatus.innerHTML = "<div class='alert alert-dismissible alert-success'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button><h4 class='alert-heading'>Success!</h4><p class='mb-0'>Your data has been sent successfully!</p></div>";
                }
            }
        }
        ajax.send(formData);
    }
}
```

I use formData.append() to get all the values and send it to my php script. But it won't send, I don't know what is the problem. I use the Inspect Element but no errors occurred.

Here is my Ajax Module:

```
function ajaxObj(method, url) {
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open(method, url, true);
    x.setRequestHeader("Content-type","multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8; boundary=" + Math.random().toString().substr(2));
    return x;
}

function ajaxReturn(x) {
    if(x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is my PHP script:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['lrn']) && !empty($_POST['lrn'])) {
        include 'dbconn.php';

        $lrn = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['lrn']);
        $studentFname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['studentFname']);
        $studentLname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['studentLname']);
        $studentMname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['studentMname']);
        $studentSname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['studentSname']);
        $gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['gender']);
        $dob = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['dob']);
        $citizenship = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['citizenship']);
        $religion = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['religion']);
        $ethnicity = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['ethnicity']);
        $motherTongue = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['motherTongue']);
        $houseNum = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['houseNum']);
        $street = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['street']);
        $village = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['village']);
        $brgy = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['brgy']);
        $city = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['city']);
        $province = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['province']);
        $tel = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['tel']);
        $mobile = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['mobile']);
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
        $fatherName = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['fatherName']);
        $fatherNum = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['fatherNum']);
        $motherName = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['motherName']);
        $motherNum = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['motherNum']);
        $guardianName = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['guardianName']);
        $guardianNum = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['guardianNum']);
        $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $fileTmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
        $fileError = $_FILES['file']['error'];
        $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];

        // File upload validation
        if(!empty($fileName)) {
            $fileExtn = explode(".", $fileName);
            $fileActualExtn = strtolower(end($fileExtn));

            $allowedType = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'doc', 'docx', 'zip', 'rar', 'pdf');
            if(in_array($fileActualExtn, $allowedType)) {
                if($fileError == 0) {
                    if($fileSize < 10000) {
                        $fileNewName = uniqid('', true).".".$fileActualExtn;
                        $fileDestination = "../uploads/".$fileNewName;
                        move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);
                    } else {
                        echo "<p class='statusMsg red'><i class='fa fa-exclamation-triangle' aria-hidden='true'></i> Please upload a file that is less than 10mb!</p>";
                        exit();
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "<p class='statusMsg red'><i class='fa fa-exclamation-triangle' aria-hidden='true'></i> There was an error uploading your file, please try again!</p>";
                    exit();
                }
            } else {
                echo "<p class='statusMsg red'><i class='fa fa-exclamation-triangle' aria-hidden='true'></i> This file type is not allowed to upload!</p>";
                exit();
            }
        } else {
            $fileNewName = "";
        }

        $sql = "SELECT lrn FROM students";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $resultCount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if($resultCount > 0) {
            echo "<p class='statusMsg red'><i class='fa fa-exclamation-triangle' aria-hidden='true'></i> LRN was already in the database!</p>";
            exit();
        }

        // Date of Birth Validation
        function isRealDate($dob) { 
            if(false === strtotime($dob)) { 
                return false;
            }

            list($year, $month, $day) = explode('-', $dob); 
            return checkdate($month, $day, $year);
        }

        if(isRealDate($dob) != true) {
            echo "<p class='statusMsg red'><i class='fa fa-exclamation-triangle' aria-hidden='true'></i> Date of Birth is invalid!</p>";
            exit();
        }

        if(empty($lrn) || empty($studentFname) || empty($studentLname) || empty($studentMname) || empty($gender) || empty($dob) || empty($religion) || empty($houseNum) || empty($street) || empty($brgy) || empty($city) || empty($province) || empty($zip) || empty($mobile) || empty($email)) {
            echo "<p class='statusMsg red'><i class='fa fa-exclamation-triangle' aria-hidden='true'></i> Please fill out all required fields!</p>";
            exit();
        } elseif(empty($fatherName) && empty($motherName) && empty($guardianName)) {
            echo "<p class='statusMsg red'><i class='fa fa-exclamation-triangle' aria-hidden='true'></i> Provide atleast one of your guardian(s)!</p>";
            exit();
        } elseif(!is_numeric($lrn) || !is_numeric($tel) || !is_numeric($mobile) || !is_numeric($fatherNum) || !is_numeric($motherNum) || !is_numeric($guardianNum)) {
            echo "<p class='statusMsg red'><i class='fa fa-exclamation-triangle' aria-hidden='true'></i> Only numbers are allowed on this fields (LRN, Telephone No., Mobile No., Guardian's Contact No.)</p>";
            exit();
        } elseif(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            echo "<p class='statusMsg red'><i class='fa fa-exclamation-triangle' aria-hidden='true'></i> Your email address is incorrect or invalid!</p>";
            exit();
        } else {
            // Get age
            $age = date_diff(date_create($dob), date_create('now'))->y;

            $studentFnameNew = ucwords(trim(preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $studentFname)));
            $studentLnameNew = ucwords(trim(preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $studentLname)));
            $studentMnameNew = ucwords(trim(preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $studentMname)));
            $studentSnameNew = ucwords(trim(preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $studentSname)));
            $citizenshipNew = ucwords(trim(preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $citizenship)));
            $religionNew = ucwords(trim(preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $religion)));
            $ethnicityNew = ucwords(trim(preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $ethnicity)));
            $motherTongueNew = ucwords(trim(preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $motherTongue)));
            $houseNumNew = ucwords(trim(preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $houseNum)));
            $streetNew = ucwords(trim(preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $street)));
            $villageNew = ucwords(trim(preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $village)));
            $brgyNew = ucwords(trim(preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $brgy)));
            $cityNew = ucwords(trim(preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $city)));
            $fatherNameNew = ucwords(trim(preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $fatherName)));
            $motherNameNew = ucwords(trim(preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $motherName)));
            $guardianNameNew = ucwords(trim(preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $guardianName)));
            $approvalStatus = 0;

            $sql = "INSERT INTO `students`(`lrn`, `student_firstname`, `student_lastname`, `student_middlename`, `student_suffixname`, `gender`, `dob`, `age`, `citizenship`, `religion`, `ethnic_group`, `mother_tongue`, `house_num`, `street`, `village`, `barangay`, `city`, `province`, `zip`, `tel`, `mobile`, `email`, `father_name`, `father_num`, `mother_name`, `mother_num`, `guardian_name`, `guardian_num`, `file`, `approval_status`) VALUES ('$lrn', '$studentFnameNew', '$studentLnameNew', '$studentMnameNew', '$studentSnameNew', '$gender', '$dob', '$age', '$citizenshipNew', '$religionNew', '$ethnicityNew', '$motherTongueNew', '$houseNumNew', '$streetNew', '$villageNew', '$brgyNew', '$cityNew', '$province', '$zip', '$tel', '$mobile', '$email', '$fatherNameNew', '$fatherNum', '$motherNameNew', '$motherNum', '$guardianNameNew', '$guardianNum', '$fileNewName', '$approvalStatus')";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            echo "success";
        }
    }
```

Comment: so do you get some errors ?

Comment: instead of that much code why not to use `$('form').serializeArray() ;` to send data in a single-shot?

Comment: You shouldn't set the boundary in the header, your boundary won't be the same as what `FormData` actually sends.

Comment: @AlivetoDie There's a `type="file"` input, you can't serialize that, you have to use `FormData`.

Comment: @PHPdev He's posting with AJAX, the form tag is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use this:

```
x.setRequestHeader("Content-type","multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8; boundary=" + Math.random().toString().substr(2));
```

`XMLHttpRequest` uses its own boundary between the form elements, it won't match your random boundary. If you leave this out, the proper header is sent automatically.